# Capturar anexos de email ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

tudo bem?
Estou iniciando os estudos em ASP.NET MVC (C#) e gostaria que pudessem me ajudar com um problema que estou bem perdido.

Estou precisando conectar em uma caixa postal e capturar todos os anexos que tem disponível nela.

> Estou á procura de materiais de estudo ou códigos que façam essa rotina para que eu faça testes.

Ficarei muito grato com sua ajuda.

Comment: Pedro, tente melhorar sua pergunta. Não tendo nada pronto ou um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) dificilmente conseguirá ajuda.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann tudo bem? Estou tentando capturar os anexos de uma caixa postal. Mas como estou iniciando os estudos em ASP.NET MVC não faço ideia e não encontro na internet nenhum conteudo sobre isso. Queria algo para ler, ou um codigo para ter como base. Abraços.

Comment: Pedro, você não deu nenhum cenário de exemplo, não informou se já recebe esses e-mails de algum forma ou se quer ler de um provedor existente, então vou te enviar algo que, pelo menos, possa te nortear em alguma pesquisa: [ler do gmail (SOen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056715/reading-emails-from-gmail-in-c-sharp) e [ler do exchange (SOen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c-sharp)